# how to serialize Scala Array of types to JSON array in HTTP response using Spray?

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

I am a Spray newby, somewhat proficient in Scala, and although the Spray documentation is overall very good, I can't find any relevant example for my problem.  I am trying to do something very simple:  serialize (or Marshall) a Scala Array of my type to a json array, using either json4s or spray-json.  In this example I use spray-json, with the following entry in build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.3.2"
)
```

The code below produces the following compiler error:

```
[error] /Users/scott/integration/src/main/scala/com/anomaly/rest/AnomalyService.scala:101: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Array[com.anomaly.model.KDEOutlier]
[error]  required: spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
[error]             complete(outlierService.getOutliersOverTime(startTime, endTime))

/* request handling actor and service */

package com.anomaly.rest

import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.event.slf4j.SLF4JLogging
import spray.routing._
import spray.http._
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._
import MediaTypes._

import anomaly.model.KDEOutlier
import anomaly.dal.KDEOutliersDAO

class AnomalyServiceActor extends Actor with AnomalyService {
  def actorRefFactory = context
  def receive = runRoute(anomaliesRoute)
}

trait AnomalyService extends HttpService with SLF4JLogging {
  val outlierService = KDEOutliersDAO
  val anomaliesRoute = respondWithMediaType(MediaTypes.`application/json`) {
    path("anomalies/overtime ") {
      get {
        parameters('startTime.as[Long], 'endTime.as[Long]) { (startTime, endTime) =>
            complete(outlierService.getOutliersOverTime(startTime, endTime))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


/* model */

package com.anomaly.model
import java.util.Date

case class KDEOutlier(date: Long, score: Double)


/* dao service called by request handler service */

package com.anomaly.dal

import java.util.Date
import com.anomaly.model.KDEOutlier
import com.anomaly.model.KDERawOutlier

object KDEOutliersDAO {  
    def getOutliersOverTime(startTime: Long, endTime: Long): Array[KDEOutlier] = {
        Array(KDEOutlier(Date.UTC(2013,5,2,0,0,0),0.7695), KDEOutlier(Date.UTC(2013,5,3,0,0,0),0.7648),
                KDEOutlier(Date.UTC(3,5,4,0,0,0),0.7645), KDEOutlier(Date.UTC(2013,5,5,0,0,0),0.7638),
                KDEOutlier(Date.UTC(2013,5,6,0,0,0),0.8549), KDEOutlier(Date.UTC(2013,5,7,0,0,0),0.9562),
                KDEOutlier(Date.UTC(2013,5,9,0,0,0),0.7574), KDEOutlier(Date.UTC(2013,5,10,0,0,0),0.7543))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need define an implicit `RootJsonFormat` (for example `jsonFormat2(KDEOutlier)`) and `import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._`:

```
package com.anomaly.rest

import com.scalakata._

import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.event.slf4j.SLF4JLogging
import spray.routing._
import spray.http._
import spray.json._
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._
import MediaTypes._
import java.util.Date

case class KDEOutlier(date: Long, score: Double)

class AnomalyServiceActor extends Actor with AnomalyService {
  def actorRefFactory = context
  def receive = runRoute(anomaliesRoute)
}

trait AnomalyService extends HttpService with SLF4JLogging {

  implicit val outlierFormat = jsonFormat2(KDEOutlier)

  val anomaliesRoute = respondWithMediaType(MediaTypes.`application/json`) {
    path("anomalies/overtime ") {
      get {
        parameters('startTime.as[Long], 'endTime.as[Long]) { (startTime, endTime) => {
          val result = Array(KDEOutlier(Date.UTC(2013,5,2,0,0,0),0.7695), KDEOutlier(Date.UTC(2013,5,3,0,0,0),0.7648),
                KDEOutlier(Date.UTC(3,5,4,0,0,0),0.7645), KDEOutlier(Date.UTC(2013,5,5,0,0,0),0.7638),
                KDEOutlier(Date.UTC(2013,5,6,0,0,0),0.8549), KDEOutlier(Date.UTC(2013,5,7,0,0,0),0.9562),
                KDEOutlier(Date.UTC(2013,5,9,0,0,0),0.7574), KDEOutlier(Date.UTC(2013,5,10,0,0,0),0.7543))
          complete(result)
        }                                                     }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can try this snippet on http://scalakata.com

Comment: Thank you, I have also added that import.  I am still getting the same compiler error as above though.

Comment: OK - do you have an implicit instance of `RootJsonFormat[KDEOutlier]` in scope? e.g. `jsonFormat2(KDEOutlier)`?

Comment: Yes, tried this below, neither the jsonFormat2 way worked (actually produced an additional error to the one already shown), nor the commented out line:

Comment: object AnomalyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit object outlierResultFormat extends RootJsonFormat[KDEOutlier] {
        // def write(o: KDEOutlier) = JsArray(JsNumber(o.date), JsNumber(o.score))
        def write(o: KDEOutlier) = jsonFormat2(KDEOutlier)
    }
}

Comment: Also tried:               object AnomalyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val outlierFormat = jsonFormat2(KDEOutlier)
  }           (didn't work either)
}

Comment: Updated the answer with an example - does that work for you?